# how to use react-navigation using redux saga

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, redux-saga

I have a Login screen to login if the status is 200 I needs to navigate the user to another screen. I'm using redux saga to handle the side effects. How to navigate the user to another if the response status is 200.

**LoginSaga.js**

```
import {call, put} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {Alert} from 'react-native';
import LoginActions from '../../Login/LoginActions';
import {navigate} from '../../../Service/NavigationService';
import {getAuth} from '../../../Service/LoginService';

export function* fetchAuthSaga(authInfo) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(getAuth, authInfo);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      navigate('Registration');
      yield put(LoginActions.fetchAuthSuccess(response.data));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(LoginActions.fetchAuthFailure(err));
    return Alert.alert('Username or Password incorrect');
  }
}
```

**NavigationService.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function goBack() {
  navigationRef.current?.goBack();
}
export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

navigate function showing undefined. How to fix this

Thanks, advance!!

Comment: Are you sure that you followed through everything that's mentioned in the [navigating without the navigation prop tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/)? Check again, maybe you missed something, because `navigate` shouldn't be `undefined`. Also pay attention to [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/#handling-initialization) section of the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the ref in the navigation container. Now it's working fine